# Java How to flip bits of an array to random values

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

How could you create a method that could flip 2 bits (ranges 00-11 Hence 0-3) in a byte, Randomly!

Example
[image: Example]

```
Coin flip one:   111 01 111
Coin flip two:   111 11 111
Coin flip three: 111 01 111
Coin flip four:  111 10 111
```

What I'm working with

```
private static void coinFlip(byte theByte)
    {
        Integer mode = new Random().nextInt(3);
        byte value = mode.byteValue();
        byte tmp = value & 255;
            tmp = tmp >> 4;
            tmp = tmp & 3;
           //Point of confusion
           //Now stuff it back in index 5 & 4 ?
    }
```

Comment: Evolutionary algorithm homework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
   private static byte coinFlip(byte theByte)
    {
        Integer mode = new Random().nextInt(3);
        byte value = mode.byteValue();
        return (byte)(theByte ^ (value << 3));
    }
```

Last line is simply XORING your byte with the two shifted random bits.

Comment: And you my friend, are the winner!

Comment: To flip the bits in your example / image, << 3 should be correct. (ie, you will leave the lowest 3 bits unchanged)

Comment: You should use `int` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: @starblue how would you convert to byte value with 'int'

Comment: I don't believe this is correct.  `0^0 = 0`, `0^1 = 1`, but `1^0 != 0` and `1^1 != 1`.  OR (`|`) is closer, but still misses since `1|0 != 0`

Comment: @Mrshll Normally by casting, but in this case you shouldn't even do that and use `mode` directly in the return statement. `Integer` is only for situations where you need an object, for example when putting integers in collections.

Comment: @femtoRgon, you can view XOR as flipping if the second operand is 1 (0^1 = 1, 1^1=0), and not flipping if it is 0 (0^0=0, 1^0=1). Therefore we are flipping those two bits on a random basis.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Doesn't set it to exactly the value obtained from Random.nextInt, as I was thinking, but it randomizes just as effectively.  Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

Filling in using similar methods to what you are using, I think this should work:

```
private static byte coinFlip(byte theByte)
{
    //Get random value of form 000xx000
    Integer mode = new Random().nextInt(3);
    byte value = mode.byteValue();
    value = value << 3;
    //Mask the result byte, to format xxx00xxx
    byte mask = 231; //0b11100111
    byte maskedByte = theByte & mask;
    //return 000xx000 | xxx00xxx
    return maskedByte | value;
}
```

As fge said, though, BitSet is the saner way to do it.

Comment: where does maskedByte come from in your example?

Comment: why do you do this part --> byte mask = (255-3) << 3 ?

Comment: Creating a bitmask.  Looking at it now, this isn't actually correct, but here is the idea:  In binary:  (11111111 - 00000011) << 3 = (11111100) << 3 = (but not really) 11100111.  Perhaps it would be simpler to just use 11100111 = 231.

Comment: Will this preserve the other bits in the byte?

Comment: That's the idea, yes.  if we start with 10101010:  10101010 & 11100111 = 10100010, and then 000xx000 | 10100010 = 101xx010.

Comment: @Mrshll187 I was wrong in thinking Helmuth M.'s answer was not adequate.  You should give it another look (see his last comment).  Much nicer than what I have here, clearly the best answer, to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set a bit at index `n`, use:

```
b |= 1 << n;
```

if you want to unset a bit at index `n`, use:

```
b &= ~(1 << n);
```

Or use a [BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html) (which has a convenient enough `.flip()` method).

Comment: flip wont change them randomly. and I need to to have two bits flip and push it back to the same byte

Comment: No, but you can select integers randomly ;)

Comment: Could you point me to an example. I'm not the most familiar with BitSet

Comment: Just create a `new BitSet(8)`, that will create a bit set of 8 bits (therefore a byte), all set to 0 to begin with. Then flip into this bitset as you see fit.

Comment: Alternatively, getting a BitSet with `BitSet.valueOf(Byte[])` rather than the no-arg constructor, then modifying the bits in question with `BitSet.set(index, value)` might be a more intuitive use.

Comment: @femtoRgon how do you return the altered object(bitset) back to a byte then

Comment: @fge in java 1.6 there is no toByteArray() method in BitSet. Alternatives?

Comment: Argh... I know of one, yes, but I have to dig the code out :/

Comment: Yes, looks like `toByteArray()` came in Java 7.  In Java 6, you may have to convert it manually (loop through bits in BitSet { if bit is set: `byte |= 1 << index` })